# Seeking City boundary shapefile of Podgorica (Montenegro)?

Tags: data, administrative-boundaries, montenegro

I work with QGis 2.18.1 in Austria and need the city boundaries of Podgorica which is located in Montenegro.

Do you know where I can get or download it for free?

Comment: When seeking open data, even if it is spatial data, I would recommend researching/asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the data from OpenStreetMap. I don't know if you're familiar with the Overpass API, and I also don't know if that data from OSM is accurate.

One way of doing it is by using [overpass-turbo.eu](http://overpass-turbo.eu). After finding Podgorica, use this expression in the Wizard:

`place=city and name=Podgorica`

Build the query and Run it. You will get the city boundary as well as a point. You can get rid of the point if you delete the line starting with *node*. You can export the result as a GeoJSON in WGS84, which you can open in QGIS. 
The same thing can be done in QGIS using the QuickOSM plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I tried it like you said and got some results. Unfortunately these weren´t accurante enough.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question: [Looking for a Free Shapefile of the European Countries](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177741/looking-for-a-free-shapefile-of-the-european-countries) and the first answer which will direct you to Eurostat and the dataset [NUTS 2013](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts#nuts13)

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer but I had a look at all of those links and I couldn´t find the boundaries of Podgorica. Only the borders of the country (Montenegro) but they are not sufficient for my research. Kind regards.

Comment: Ok i thought Podgorica was another name for Montenegro